# Converting Oracle date to Access Data format

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Good morning,

I a linking to an Oracle Data (table) through ODBC. I do not have any control over how this table is design or the data is stored.

However, the data column in coming in as text data type in the following format, example: 20120110

I used the following code to convert the date in access:

`CDate(Right([Example.MY_DATE],2) & "/" & Mid([Example.MY_DATE],5,2) & "/" & Left([Example.MY_DATE],4))`

This converts the date to: 01/10/2012

Is this the right way to get this going?

I am getting mix results, meaning my result set on my query is not accurate, I just want to make sure my conversion method is right.

Example:

`SELECT

CDate(Right([Example.MY_DATE],2) & "/" & Mid([Example.MY_DATE],5,2) & "/" & Left([Example.MY_DATE],4)) AS Format_Date

WHERE (((CDate(Right([xample.MY_DATE],2) & "/" & Mid([xample.MY_DATE],5,2) & "/" & Left([xample.MY_DATE],4)))>#01/09/2012#)

ORDER BY

CDate(Right([Example.MY_DATE],2) & "/" & Mid([Example.MY_DATE],5,2) & "/" & Left([Example.MY_DATE],4))`

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the 'DateSerial' function instead:

```
Date = DateSerial(Left(MyDate, 4), Mid(MyDate, 5, 2), Right(MyDate, 2))
```

Date Serial should convert the date to the default format for your environment e.g in the English format rather than the American format etc.

So the SQL may look like this:

```
SELECT DateSerial(Left(MyDate, 4), Mid(MyDate, 5, 2), Right(MyDate, 2)) AS Format_Date
FROM Tablename
WHERE DateSerial(Left(MyDate, 4), Mid(MyDate, 5, 2), Right(MyDate, 2)) > #01/09/2012#
ORDER BY DateSerial(Left(MyDate, 4), Mid(MyDate, 5, 2), Right(MyDate, 2))
```

Comment: No I have not, can you elaborate further as to how I tied this in.
Thanks! I am reading on this also.

Comment: My answer contains the exact syntax for the function and i've tried to match it up with what you have written above, however if you type the function name in to the search box in Access then it gives an example : )

Comment: Thanks I am trying to test this out and see how it works differently from what I already have.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my version of the SQL also if it helps

Comment: I am getting errors, Missing Operator, wrong number of arguments. However, I do not want to drag this on, I got the idea and will have to play around with this. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Ah, my mistake, you only need name Year,Month,Day when working with dates, not strings, I have fixed my answer.